# WPF RichTextBox tokenized editing

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am trying to enable the user to edit specific parts of a text (and only those parts) using a `RichTextBox` control.

My approach consists of using `TextBox` controls contained in `InlineUIContainer` tags in a `FlowDocument`. The code below shows what I've accomplished so far:

```
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer >
                <TextBox Text="Field" MinWidth="65"></TextBox>
            </InlineUIContainer>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <TextBlock Text="Some text..." ></TextBlock>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

The problem with this is that the user is able to select the elements in the `FlowDocument` and delete them... worse they can edit any text that is part of a `Run` element or even cut/paste text in the document.

I had the idea to set the `IsReadOnly="True"` on the `RichTextBox` but that also disables TextBoxes from being edited... Also I could handle the PreviewKeyDown but that can not handle every situation (i.e.: Right clicking and pressing paste).

I was wondering if there is any alternative solution or even an alternative library or third party control that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting the `IsReadOnly` property of the `TextBox` to `false` and the `IsReadOnly` property of the `RichTextBox` to `true`?:

```
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer >
                <TextBox Text="Field" MinWidth="65" IsReadOnly="False"></TextBox>
            </InlineUIContainer>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <TextBlock Text="Some text..." ></TextBlock>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Nice.  I would not have expected `IsReadOnly` to be an inherited property, and yet it is.